# infinite loop in makefiile

Tags: c, makefile

I read about recursive variable in makefiles.  Because we put '=' in the following code, it's a recursive variable, as apposed to ':='

```
CC = gcc -Wall
# we want to add something to the end of the variable
CC = $(CC) -g
hello.o: hello.c hello_api .h
$(CC) -c hello.c -o hello.o
```

I didn't understand still, why in this case we have an infinent loop.

Comment: This does not look like a valid Makefile to me. First of all, the invocation of the $(CC) command should be preceded by a <TAB> character. Also, seems like `hello_api` and `.h` should not be separated.

Answer (score 8):

From the [manual](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/make-3.79/html_chapter/make_6.html):

> The first flavor of variable is a *recursively expanded* variable. [...] The value you specify is installed verbatim; if it contains references to other variables, these references are expanded whenever this variable is substituted (in the course of expanding some other string). When this happens, it is called *recursive expansion*.

Your `CC` variable is of this flavour. It's content is literally `$(CC) -g`; it is *not* `gcc -Wall -g`. So when you expand this variable, you first expand `$(CC)`, which again contains the reference to itself, and so you have infinite recursion.

The difference when using `:=` is that the right-hand-side is evaluated immediately and the *result* is assigned to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use
    CC += -g
in the 5th line

More information here http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors

Answer (score -1):

Your `Makefile` is wrong; should be (assuming a *GNU make*)

```
 RM= rm -vf
 CC= gcc
 CFLAGS= -Wall -g
 .PHONY: all clean
 all: hello
 hello: hello.o
 hello.o: hello.c hello_api.h
 clean:
       $(RM) *.o *~
```

<sup>Last line, just after `clean:`, starts with a tab character</sup>

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13175568/841108) for more. Run `make -p` to understand the implicit rules useful in the above case.

Read carefully the documentation on [make variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20311543/841108). Those defined with `=` are expanded lazily and textually (with the make variables further expanded in the substituted text). In other words, `CC= $(CC) -g` gives an infinite loop. Because the first `$(CC)` is replaced with `$(CC) -g` which is rescanned and its `$(CC)` is replaced with the same (getting `$(CC) -g -g`) etc etc ad infinitum.

`make` is mostly a string processing utility (with of course the dependency thing based upon file modification time). It does not really have some proper [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) as internal representation of the commands to be run.

Comment: thanks. but still, Im asking about infinite loop that can take place in a makefile due to recursive variables. Can u give a simple example and explain ?

Comment: Explanation given in [Kerrek's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20311543/841108); but I also gave a bit of it.