# How MAKE knows which source file to check

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

How this simple `make` script knows that some of cpp files is changed? Does it means that for each .o file it will look for corresponding .cpp one? What if extension will be different - for example `.c`

```
hellomake: hellomake.o hellofunc.o 
    gcc -o hellomake hellomake.o hellofunc.o -I.
```

UPD:
According to my understanding scrip I provide should not look to c and cpp files. And when I asked to build project second time `MAKE` told me "make: 'hellomake' is up to date.
 But I was surprised when I have changed `hellomake.cpp` MAKE has decided do rebuild project. Why?

Answer (score 4):

[GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make) has many builtin rules. Run `make -p` to find them. And use the existing rules in your `Makefile`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20550767/841108) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32599927/841108) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13175568/841108)

Answer (score 1):

Obvious documentation links were already provided. I just wanted to comment on your example. You told make the following:

The file `hellomake` relies on `hellomake.o` and `hellofunc.o`, ie. both are prerequisites of `hellomake`. If any prerequisite changes since the last build, `hellomake` will be rebuilt. How (re-) building is done is the second line, ie. the gcc invocation.

To answer your question: The snippet provided, will not look for any cpp files. You need different rules in addition for that, ie. something like

```
%.o: %.cpp
    gcc -I. -c @< -o $@
```

In case you are searching for a rather generic Makefile to start with, I'd recommend [this one](https://www.c-plusplus.net/forum/88418-full). It has been the basis for many of my Makefiles in use.

Comment: According to my understanding scrip I have provided should not look to c and cpp files. And when I asked to build project second time MAKE told me "make: 'hellomake' is up to date.
 But I was surprised when I have changed hellomake.cpp MAKE kas decided do rebuild project. Why?

Comment: There are implicit default rules active [read here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) - unless you overwrite them manually.