# gnu make C undefined reference to function included in library

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make, undefined-reference

UPDATE: Found the problem. It was a bug on my end and had nothing to do with make. I had edited the file to remove the preprocessor conditional and botched it.

I am attempting to compile a testing program using a makefile to handle the creation of a library of files that include functions which are used by the test. When trying to make the final executable, I receive an 'undefined reference' error. Below is my makefile and the resulting output. I have tried switching up the ordering of files and operations within my makefile, but they all resulted in failure. That leads me to believe I am missing some key component to making it work instead of needing to reorder my operations.

I am running RHEL 4 if that matters.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
LDFLAGS=-lm
AR=ar

OBJ = \
    test.o \
    disk_alloc.o \
    stringtools.o \
    path.o \
    xxmalloc.o

LIB = libtest.a
PROG = test
TAR = $(LIB) $(PROG)

all: $(TAR)

libtest.a: $(OBJ)
    $(AR) -rv $(LIB) $(OBJ)
    ranlib $(LIB)

$(PROG):
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIB) -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) $(TAR)

.PHONY: all clean

# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=4:
```

Output after executing make:

```
gcc -Wall   -c -o test.o test.c
gcc -Wall   -c -o disk_alloc.o disk_alloc.c
gcc -Wall   -c -o stringtools.o stringtools.c
gcc -Wall   -c -o path.o path.c
gcc -Wall   -c -o xxmalloc.o xxmalloc.c
ar -rv libtest.a test.o disk_alloc.o stringtools.o path.o xxmalloc.o
ar: creating libtest.a
a - test.o
a - disk_alloc.o
a - stringtools.o
a - path.o
a - xxmalloc.o
ranlib libtest.a
gcc -Wall libtest.a -o test
libtest.a(test.o): In function `disk_alloc_test_empty':
test.c:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `disk_alloc_create'
test.c:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `disk_alloc_delete'
libtest.a(test.o): In function `disk_alloc_test_read_write':
test.c:(.text+0x17b): undefined reference to `disk_alloc_create'
test.c:(.text+0x1e0): undefined reference to `disk_alloc_delete'
libtest.a(test.o): In function `disk_alloc_test_nested':
test.c:(.text+0x30a): undefined reference to `disk_alloc_create'
test.c:(.text+0x372): undefined reference to `disk_alloc_create'
test.c:(.text+0x410): undefined reference to `disk_alloc_delete'
test.c:(.text+0x426): undefined reference to `disk_alloc_delete'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Comment: Are `disk_alloc_create` and `disk_alloc_delete` in `disk_alloc.c`? Can you see those symbols in the `disk_alloc.o` file and the `libtest.a` library? Also you realize RHEL 4 is **very** old and full of **gaping** security holes, right? (As well as being entirely unmaintained at this point.)

Comment: Disregarding talk of gaping holes, yes those two functions are in disk_alloc.c and are present in the library.

Comment: @etan-reisner Looking at the disk_alloc.o file, I actually found that the symbols for disk_alloc_create and disk_alloc_delete are not found, but they are in the library. What causes this discrepancy and how can I resolve it?

Comment: When you say "they are in the library" you mean you can find them in the `libtest.a` file? Or in the source? If they are in the library then things should be working I think. If they are only in the source then they either aren't marked for export or gcc is choosing not to include them in the object file for some reason I can't imagine.

Comment: They are found in the libtest.a file, but not in disk_alloc.o.

Comment: That is certainly odd and I can't explain that. (I don't see how that's possible actually unless they are coming from some other object in the `.a` library.) And actually, have you tried simply putting `test.o` *after* `disk_alloc.o` in the library? (Hm... actually that's probably the wrong order now that I think about it.)

Comment: Rearranging the order of the object files did not seem to have an impact either way.

Comment: Can you show the definitions of the functions in the `disk_alloc.c` file? If you clean up all the `.a` and `.o` files and start building from scratch does this problem repeat (exactly)?

Comment: Check the source posted in my question for the definitions. If I clean up and rebuild, the problem still persists.

Comment: I can check out that exact repository, dump that exact Makefile in the `dttools/src` directory and run it (with a shim `test.c` that just lists the functions for symbol purposes) and I get an error about `cctools_debug` being a missing symbol but nothing about `disk_alloc_(create|delete)`. On CentOS 5 that is. Could this be a tooling issue of the ancient RHEL 4 toolsets?

Comment: Found the problem. It was a bug on my end and had nothing to do with make. I had edited the file to remove the preprocessor conditional and botched it.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to link your object files `$(OBJ)` and you might not need any `$(LIB)`, so replace

```
$(PROG):
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIB) -o $@
```

with

```
$(PROG): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

If you absolutely want to have your library, you'll need to link an object file providing `main` outside of it. Probably keep `$(LIB)` but remove `test.o` from definition of `OBJ`, and do

```
$(PROG): test.o $(LIB)
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

Read more about [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#index-_0024_005e) in `make`

And indeed, you should upgrade your Linux distribution (using RHEL4 is not reasonable these days). If possible, in 2015, use one with [GCC 5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) & `make 4.`... Consider also using [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) to debug your `Makefile`-s. See also the links in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32760257/841108) answer (including examples of short `Makefile`-s)

BTW, static libraries are generally obsolete, and in your case it might not worth having a library (even a shared one). If you really want one, make it shared, and read [Program-Library-HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) & Drepper's paper: [*How to Write a Shared Library*](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. Unfortunately, this produces a heap of 'multiple definition' errors for all the functions found in the library and still leaves the 'undefined reference' errors at the end of the command. Any other info I can give you?

Comment: The OP is linking the `libtest.a` library and so doesn't need the individual object files.

Comment: This answer still does not resolve the 'undefined reference' errors stemming from disk_alloc_create and disk_alloc_delete. I have removed reference to the library and just used the object files as well as removing only test.o and compiling that separately using your above suggestion. Both yield the same result. Seeing as neither disk_alloc_create nor disk_alloc_delete are found in the disk_alloc.o file, that leads me to believe something has gone wrong there, but I am not sure what.

Comment: We can't help more without the entire source code that your are compiling.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question, certainly not in a comment